# setting up a Wordpress site on XAMPP goes wrong

Tags: wordpress, apache, xampp, localhost

I currently upgraded my laptop to windows 10 and now XAMPP won't install my wordpress website.

I have read lots of questions where people had the same problem: Port 80 is already in use.
I couldn't find the services that need to be disabled, like Skype and W3SVC, IIS.

Now i wanted to try to change my port from 80 to 8080, I did this using the httpd.conf file. And tried setting it up but it still doesnt work. Even not when i set "hostname: localhost:8080", if i don't put 8080 behind it it will direct me to the page which says: "Error database connection couldn't be established". And when I do put 8080 behind it it will keep loading for ever.

Does someone have a better solution than stopping services/processes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after searching for a long time i finally found the answer, i found it on https://superuser.com/questions/352017/pid4-using-port-80

This worked for me:

If it is a System Process—PID 4—you need to disable the HTTP.sys driver which is started on demand by another service, such as Windows Remote Management or Print Spooler on Windows 7 or 2008.

There is two ways to disable it but the first one is safer:

1. Go to device manager, select “show hidden devices” from menu/view, go to “Non-Plug and Play Driver”/HTTP, double click it to disable it (or set it to manual, some services depended on it).
   Reboot and use netstat -nao | find ":80" to check if 80 is still used.
2. Launch RegEdit.
   Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP
   Change the value of "start" to 4, which means disabled.
   Reboot your computer.

**My solution was the second way**