# Can Windows Service be started by incoming TCP connection?

Tags: windows-services, xinetd

I'd like to make a small Windows Service, that would be shutdown most of the time, but would be automatically activated when incoming TCP (REST?) connection comes. I do not want the service to be running 24/7 just in case (albeit that might trn to be the least evil).

There were projects porting `inet.d` and `xinet.d` to Windows, but they are all abandoned, and introducing yet another dependency for a lean program is wrong.

However by the fact they were abndoned i thought it is now a standard Windows functionality?

Service Triggers documentation seems both incomplete and self-contradictionary.

- [SERVICE_TRIGGER_SPECIFIC_DATA_ITEM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/ns-winsvc-service_trigger_specific_data_item) claims that for `SERVICE_TRIGGER_TYPE_NETWORK_ENDPOINT` there is

> A `SERVICE_TRIGGER_DATA_TYPE_STRING` that specifies **the port**, named
> pipe, or RPC interface for the network endpoint.

Feels great, but totally lacks any example how to specify port and nothing but the port. But then:

- [SERVICE_TRIGGER structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/ns-winsvc-service_trigger) seems to claim there is no way to "wait" on TCP/UDP connections.

> `SERVICE_TRIGGER_TYPE_NETWORK_ENDPOINT` - The event is triggered **when a packet or request arrives** on a particular network protocol.

So far so good... But then.

> The `pTriggerSubtype` member specifies one of the following values: `RPC_INTERFACE_EVENT_GUID` or `NAMED_PIPE_EVENT_GUID`. The `pDataItems` member specifies an endpoint or interface GUID

Dead-end. You have no choice but either Windows-specific flavor of RPC or Windows-specific named pipes. And you can only specify GUID as a *data item*, not a port, as it was told above.

I wonder, which part of documentation is wrong? Can `ChangeServiceConfig2` API be used for a seemingly simple aim of starting service to respond to TCP packet coming to a specific port ?  If yes - how?

- there is also `SERVICE_TRIGGER_TYPE_FIREWALL_PORT_EVENT` but the scarce documentation seems to say the functionality is the opposite, the trigger is not remote packet incoming from a client, but instead by a local server binding to a port.

---

Some alternative avenues, from quick search:

Internet Information Server/Service seems to have "Windows Process Activation Service" and "WWW Publishing Service" components, but adding dependency upon heavy IIS feels wrong too. It also can [interfere with other HTTP servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782968) (for example WAMP systems). Imagining explaining to non-techie persons how to diagnose and resolve clashes for TCP ports makes me shiver.

I wonder if that kind of starting a service on demand can be done only programming `http.sys` driver without rest of IIS, though.

COM protocol seems ot have servers activation on demand feature, and hopefully so does DCOM, but I do not want to have DCOM dependency. It seems today much easier to find documentation, programs and network administrators for maintaining plain TCP or HTTP connections, than DCOM. I fear relying on DCOM would be more and more fragile in practice, just like relying on DDE.

DCOM and NT-RPC would also make the program non-portable if i later would decide to use other operating systems than Windows.

Really, starting a service/daemon on incoming network connection seems so obvious a task, there has to be out-of-the-box function in Windows?

Comment: Note winsvc.h does mention a TCP_PORT_EVENT_GUID (line 439) but it's not defined anywhere...

Comment: @SimonMourier frankly it looks as either a derelict from a removed feature, or a leaked sneak-peek of a feature never implemented... :-(

Comment: Or it's there but not documented.